# How to select a specific input device with PyAudio

Tags: python, linux, audio, pyaudio

When recording audio via PyAudio, how do you specify the exact input device to use?

My computer has two microphones, one built-in and one via USB, and I want to record using the USB mic. The [Stream class](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#class-stream) has an `input_device_index` for selecting the device, but it's unclear how this index correlates to the devices. For example, how do I know which device index 0 refers to? If I had to guess, I'd say 0 refers to the built-in device while 1 refers to the USB device, but I'd like to find some programmatic way of confirming this. On Linux, is there a way to get a list of these indexes and the devices they refer to?

Answer (score 43):

you can use get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index.

For instance:

```
import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')

for i in range(0, numdevices):
    if (p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
        print("Input Device id ", i, " - ", p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name'))
```

Comment: This code failed for me. Needed to also add: info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0) and then numdevices = info.get('deviceCount'). Also I needed to use p instead of self.p, and then it worked. Please fix your answer and I'll upvote it then. Thanks.

Comment: @WaynePiekarski Done. Thanks!

Comment: How do you then assign one of the devices listed to be the pyaudio device?

Comment: and how to select a input device? get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index only gets me information

Comment: `input_device_index=x` is the solution.

Comment: That is also for output devices too?

Comment: for output channels, change 'if (p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:' to 'if (p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxOutputChannels')) > 0:'

Answer (score 3):

I havent looked at `pyaudio` but I've used [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.3/) as well on few occasions.

Here is an example code that lists available `input`  and `output` `audio devices`.

```
import sounddevice as sd
print sd.query_devices()
```

As you can see from below output, when I put my headset to mic jack , `Index 1`is available as input.
`1 Jack Mic (IDT High Definition A, MME (2 in, 0 out)`

While default laptop audio microphone comes up as `index 2`

`2 Microphone Array (IDT High Defi, MME (2 in, 0 out)`

**Output**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
   0 Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input, MME (2 in, 0 out)
>  1 Jack Mic (IDT High Definition A, MME (2 in, 0 out)
   2 Microphone Array (IDT High Defi, MME (2 in, 0 out)
   3 Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output, MME (0 in, 2 out)
<  4 Speakers / Headphones (IDT High, MME (0 in, 2 out)
   5 Communication Headphones (IDT H, MME (0 in, 2 out)
   6 Primary Sound Capture Driver, Windows DirectSound (2 in, 0 out)
   7 Jack Mic (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC), Windows DirectSound (2 in, 0 out)
   8 Microphone Array (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC), Windows DirectSound (2 in, 0 out)
   9 Primary Sound Driver, Windows DirectSound (0 in, 2 out)
  10 Speakers / Headphones (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC), Windows DirectSound (0 in, 2 out)
  11 Communication Headphones (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC), Windows DirectSound (0 in, 2 out)
  12 Communication Headphones (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC), Windows WASAPI (0 in, 2 out)
  13 Speakers / Headphones (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC), Windows WASAPI (0 in, 2 out)
  14 Jack Mic (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC), Windows WASAPI (2 in, 0 out)
  15 Microphone Array (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC), Windows WASAPI (2 in, 0 out)
  16 Headset Microphone (Bluetooth Hands-free Audio), Windows WDM-KS (1 in, 0 out)
  17 Headphones (Bluetooth Hands-free Audio), Windows WDM-KS (0 in, 2 out)
  18 Headphones (HpOut), Windows WDM-KS (0 in, 2 out)
  19 Microphone Array (MicIn2), Windows WDM-KS (2 in, 0 out)
  20 Jack Mic (MuxedIn), Windows WDM-KS (2 in, 0 out)
  21 Dock Mic (MuxedIn), Windows WDM-KS (2 in, 0 out)
  22 Rec. Playback (MuxedIn), Windows WDM-KS (2 in, 0 out)
  23 Speakers (Speaker/HP), Windows WDM-KS (0 in, 2 out)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use @slegroux awesome code to find the audio index:

```
import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')

for i in range(0, numdevices):
    if (p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
        print("Input Device id ", i, " - ", p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name'))
```

Once you find which index the microphone you want to use is on, add the input_device_index option followed by the index of the microphone (in my case the mic was on index 1) to your p.open() like so:

```
stream = p.open(
    format=FORMAT,
    channels=CHANNELS,
    rate=RATE,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
    input_device_index=1
)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The index of your microphone (that you are currently using) is always 1. You can test this with the code by @Anil_M:

```
import sounddevice as sd
print(sd.query_devices())
```

Run this code and then look at index one. Now unplug your mic and run the code again. Mic will still be on 1

Only if you want use another device, like in my case i need the OS audio you can to use following code:

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# if there is no speaker device this all makes no sense anyways
try:
    wasapi_info = p.get_host_api_info_by_type(pyaudio.paWASAPI)
except OSError:
    exit()

#choosing the speaker device 
default_speakers=p.get_device_info_by_index(wasapi_info["defaultOutputDevice"]) 

# or "defaultInputDevice"
```

I do have to mention that this code only works on windows

Answer (score 0):

In the [PyAudio Documentation](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.Stream.__init__) it states that you can define an `input_device_index`.

To find out what that device index is, you can follow the code provided in this [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/mansam/9332445) or by following the code found on the [Raspberry Pi Forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=224856) which provides an example of the outputted code.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the input device using [PulseAudio](https://wiki.debian.org/PulseAudio).

Answer (score -3):

I don't know about PyAudio, but with the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) module it goes like that:

```
python3 -m sounddevice
```

Answer (score -3):

Just use `arecord -l` to list all available input devices.