# Use webcam microphone in python on the jetson nano

Tags: python, speech-recognition, gstreamer, pyaudio, nvidia-jetson-nano

I want to use the microphone in my logitech c525 webcamera for speech recognition, on my jetson nano. I can detect the microphone and seems to work in the sound app. But im not able to find it when using python code. I have tried gstreamer, this just made a mp4 file with a high pitch noice that lasted longer than i recorded for.
I have also tried speech_recognition module, with pyaudio. Where speech_recognition.Microphone() should connect to the microphone input, here i get no response.

Any inputs or tips would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As recommended in [documentation](https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/#the-microphone-class) you need to list microphone names first to figure out which microphone is mapped to your USB one:

```
>>> sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()
['HDA Intel PCH: ALC272 Analog (hw:0,0)',
 'HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 0 (hw:0,3)',
 'sysdefault',
 'front',
 'surround40',
 'surround51',
 'surround71',
 'hdmi',
 'pulse',
 'dmix', 
 'default']
```

Once you know the device index you can select it in pyaudio

```
>>> # This is just an example; do not run
>>> mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=3)
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894315/how-to-select-a-specific-input-device-with-pyaudio).

Comment: Hi @Nikolay, Thank you for answer. I already knew the device index for the microphone. But still using 
`
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone(device_index=11) as source:
      audio = r.listen
       try:
             print(r.recognize_google(audio)
       except:
             #some error handling
`
Doesent seem to do anything. It doesnt finish or anything it just runs until i force stop it. 

And vosk is not supported on the jetson nano it seems.