# Python get Speech to text voice audio data

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

I need your help because at the moment I use "engine.say()" from "pyttsx3" so my program "speaks" with me. That's already working but now I want an audio visualizer for this voice how can I do that?

### Example

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

engine.say("Hello World")
engine.runAndWait()
```

And I want [something like this](https://res.cloudinary.com/featureupvote/image/upload/f_auto/1_bphhav.jpg).

### What I have

```
import pyaudio
import struct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mic = pyaudio.PyAudio()
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 5000
CHUNK = 3000#int(RATE/20)
stream = mic.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, output=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,6))
x = np.arange(0, 2 * CHUNK, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-500, 500)
ax.set_xlim(0, CHUNK)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.random.rand(CHUNK))


while True:
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    data = np.frombuffer(data, np.int16)
    line.set_ydata(data)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

This already visualizes my microphone audio but how can I make the voice the source?
Hope you can help me Thank you very much!

Comment: Please try to make this yourself, and then come to us with more specific issues.

Comment: https://github.com/djfun/audio-visualizer-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is - [Realtime_PyAudio_FFT](https://github.com/tr1pzz/Realtime_PyAudio_FFT)

One of the benefits of this is that

> Starts a stream_reader that pulls live audio data from any source using PyAudio (soundcard, microphone, ...)

Since you'll be playing the audio using `pyttsx3` it can extract the audio from the soundcard and would show a live visualization. This is a far better option for your case instead of extracting it via the microphone.

Also, you may need to enable threading or multiprocessing to visualize the audio if it's being executed by the same thread. Here's a good guide on that - [threading or multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207309/how-to-run-functions-in-parallel)

Comment: This is really cool Thank you. But this also just takes my microphone not the voice do you know why?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can you give an example? If you want the voice to be configured without the use of a mic then use sound-card option to do this. Look into the documentation as how this should be implemented.

Comment: Im sorry but I dont find the documentation on the github? Or the option for the soundcard

Comment: Having had another look — it seems as though the instructions are only a pipeline, i.e. soundcard input can be enabled in many other ways. One example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894315/how-to-select-a-specific-input-device-with-pyaudio). You can of-course obtain and do in any way as you wish

Comment: There I just get my headset and Microsoft Soundmapper(input) but nothing for the voice?

Comment: yes, because the voice will be retrieved/inputted from the soundcard. Consider that simply as a controller that handles input/output of audio. If you want voice then enable a microphone option instead of a soundcard.

Comment: But when I enable this soundcard option in devices it still just gets my mic audio and not the other

Comment: Play around and research and you will probably figure out the error. If the error still persists, post it as another question and @me here to get my attention. If this answer helped with your initial question — feel free to accept it.