# Record mic with pyaudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

I try to record my mic with pyaudio. So I use the example program:

```
import pyaudio
import wave

if __name__ == "__main__":
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 16000
    CHUNK = 1024
    RECORD_SECONDS = 6
    WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = 'filename'

    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    list_audio = []
    for x in range(0, pa.get_device_count()):
        info = pa.get_device_info_by_index(x)
        print("info {0}".format(info))

    # start Recording
    stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                        rate=RATE, input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
                        # sample_rate=RATE)
    print("recording...")
    print('---------------------------------')
    print(int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS))
    print('*********************************')

    frames = []

    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        print("Recording . . .")

        frames.append(data)
    print("Recording finished. . .")

    # stop Recording
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()

    waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
    waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    waveFile.setsampwidth(2)
    audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT)
    waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
    waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    waveFile.close()
```

When I run it, my wav file is only noise. I work on ubuntu 18.04.
I think this come from pulse/alsa compatibility. But when I use my mic on skype there is no trouble.

Also when I try to record a specific device I get that error:

```
device {'index': 0, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'HDA Intel PCH: ALC293 Analog (hw:0,0)', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 2, 'maxOutputChannels': 2, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.005804988662131519, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.005804988662131519, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
 ....
 device {'index': 4, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 3 (hw:0,9)', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 8, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.005804988662131519, 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
 device {'index': 5, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 4 (hw:0,10)', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 8, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.005804988662131519, 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
 device {'index': 6, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'AK5371: USB Audio (hw:1,0)', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 2, 'maxOutputChannels': 0, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008684807256235827, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
Chosen index: 6
 device {'index': 7, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'HD USB CAMERA: Audio (hw:2,0)', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 2, 'maxOutputChannels': 0, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008684807256235827, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
 device {'index': 8, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'Jabra SPEAK 510 USB: Audio (hw:3,0)', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 1, 'maxOutputChannels': 2, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.0239375, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.0239375, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.096, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.096, 'defaultSampleRate': 16000.0}
 device {'index': 9, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'sysdefault', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 128, 'maxOutputChannels': 128, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultSampleRate': 48000.0}
 device {'index': 10, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'front', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 2, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.005804988662131519, 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
 device {'index': 11, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'surround40', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 2, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.005804988662131519, 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
 device {'index': 12, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'surround51', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 2, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.005804988662131519, 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
 device {'index': 13, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'surround71', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 2, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.005804988662131519, 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
 device {'index': 14, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'hdmi', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 8, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.005804988662131519, 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
 device {'index': 15, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'pulse', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 32, 'maxOutputChannels': 32, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
 device {'index': 16, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'dmix', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 2, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultSampleRate': 48000.0}
 device {'index': 17, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'default', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 32, 'maxOutputChannels': 32, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.008707482993197279, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
Expression 'paInvalidSampleRate' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2048
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_InitialConfigure( &self->capture, inParams, self->primeBuffers, hwParamsCapture, &realSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2719
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, &outputLatency, &hostBufferSizeMode )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2843
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xavier/dev/3003_mdt/module-test-gui/controller.py", line 165, in start_record_bag
    stream_callback=self.new_frame)
  File "/home/xavier/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xavier/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9997] Invalid sample rate
```

I also try to collect my data with pyQt but I have no good result:

```
def on_new_audio_data(self, buff: QtMultimedia.QAudioBuffer):
    with self.mutex:
        import ctypes
        audio_data = AudioData()
        length_array = buff.sampleCount()
        byte_array = (ctypes.c_uint8 * length_array).from_address(buff.constData().__int__())
        # val = struct.unpack('<BBh', byte_array)

        byte_buffer = bytearray()
        for short_index in range(0,len(byte_array)):
            byte_buffer.append(byte_array[short_index])
```

There a zero value every two byte ...

Comment: Do you have more than 1 input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to see whether you are using the right input device. Add the `input_device_index={the right input device}` argument to the `audio.open`.

You can check the ids of your devices like so: [How to select a specific input device with PyAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894315/how-to-select-a-specific-input-device-with-pyaudio)

```py
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')
for i in range(0, numdevices):
        if (p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
            print "Input Device id ", i, " - ", p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name')
```

Comment: I edit my first post to add more information

Comment: Try to match the default sample rate of the device like so `pyaudio.get_device_info_by_index(device_index).get('defaultSampleRate'))`

Comment: I gte the same problem with the default audio input framerate.

Comment: In fact it seems to work with default device rate. But on my other computer I get that error:OSError: [Errno -9981] Input overflowed

Comment: Alter `frames_per_buffer=2048` and try again.