# How to choose sound device in python

Tags: python, pyaudio

'Soundcard' or 'PyAudio' python libraries allow to choose input device for recording sound from mic and output device for playing sound. But it can't choose device for "listenning" sound.
I installed 'Virtual Audio Cable' which creates 'Virtual input' and 'Virtual output' which allows to record sound from system directly. It works but I have to choose them in windows properties anyway. How can I choose sound devices from Python only?

Comment: That is entirely dependent on the library you are using.  All of the libraries have mechanisms for choosing the audio endpoint.  You'll need to dig in to the documentation, or the source code.

Comment: I tried 'PyAudio', 'Sounddevise', 'Soundcard' libraries. All of them allows to choose sound devices but only for playing and recording sound. They don't allow to change sound devices in windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894315/how-to-select-a-specific-input-device-with-pyaudio  describes how to do it for both pyaudio and sounddevice.

Comment: it's different themes