# Accessing Raspberry Pi4 USB port with Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, usb

I am using Raspberry Pi 4 which comes with 4 USB ports. For my project, I have two mics and both will be connected to Rsp via a USB port. I need to be able to choose which Mic needs to be ON. So basically I need to be able to switch/choose which USB port I want the sound to come in.

I need to be able to choose Mic1 or Mic2. I am writing my code in Python. Is there any library that gives me access to choose a specific UBS port? I really can't find anything.

Appreciate your help.

Regards

Comment: you should rather use modules like `PyAudio` and select `microphone` from `list of allowed devices`, not select `USB`, and read data from this device.

Comment: [python - How to select a specific input device with PyAudio - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894315/how-to-select-a-specific-input-device-with-pyaudio)